# HTML Keyboard Navigation Link

Tags: html

I'm testing a website with keyboard navigation. When I do TAB I can see the highlight jump between links in document order. Now I would like to enhance the navigation by setting a link, eg the 4th link, once there's a keyword ENTER hit or mouse click, the highlight would jump to the 20th link for example. Is it possible?

Comment: Do you want to change focused link when user press "enter" on a specific element? try focus() inside an onclick handler...

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti sounds like a feasible one I'll give a try. Thanks.

Comment: it should work and using some jquery will be pretty short and reusable, like `$(".fordward.focus").click(function () { $($(this).data("forward-to")).focus() });`

Comment: Thanks, it looks good. http://jsfiddle.net/jrkfhexb/2/

Comment: Not what I meant, I posted an answer with a better working example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting from your fiddle imagine to have this list of links:

```
<a href="#" id="link1" class="forward-link" data-forward-to="link2">Link 1</a>
<a href="#" id="link2" class="forward-link" data-forward-to="link3">Link 2</a>
<a href="#" id="link3" class="forward-link" data-forward-to="link4">Link 3</a>
<a href="#" id="link4" class="forward-link" data-forward-to="link5">Link 4</a>
<a href="#" id="link5">Link 5</a>
```

Note:

- Each target link has an `id` (also `link1` but it's not required).
- Each link that will forward focus to another link is *decorated* with `forward-link` class.
- Each link that will forward focus to another link has a `data-forward-to` attribute, it contains the id of the link (actually any foucusable control is allowed) that will receive focus when element is clicked.

Now in markup we have all information we need, a small script will attach an handler for `onclick` on each element decorated with `forward-link` and it'll use its `data-forward-to` attribute value to forward focus (please note here I'm using jQuery - do not forget to include it in fiddles! - just to keep code short but it's not mandatory/really useful):

```
$(".forward-link").click(function () {
    $("#"+$(this).data("forward-to")).focus();
});
```

Answer (score -2):

taken from: (I've change the code a little) 
[Tabbing navigation](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.11.1)

Here is an example: (Take a look at the tabindex)

With tabindex you can set the TAB jump order.

```
!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>A document with FORM</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
...some text...
<P>Go to the 
<A tabindex="10" href="http://www.w3.org/">W3C Web site.</A>
...some more...
<BUTTON type="button" name="get-database"
           tabindex="5" onclick="get-database">
Get the current database.
</BUTTON>
...some more...
<FORM action="..." method="post">
<P>
<INPUT tabindex="1" type="text" name="field1">
<INPUT tabindex="2" type="text" name="field2">
<INPUT tabindex="0" type="text" name="field2">
<INPUT tabindex="3" type="submit" name="submit">
</P>
</FORM>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Here another:

```
!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>A document with FORM</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>

<a href="http://www.w3schools.com/html/0" tabindex="0" >Visit our HTML tutorial</a>
<br/>
<a href="http://www.w3schools.com/html/1" tabindex="3">Visit our HTML tutorial</a>
<br/>
<a href="http://www.w3schools.com/html/2" tabindex="2">Visit our HTML tutorial</a>
<br/>
<a href="http://www.w3schools.com/html/3" tabindex="1">Visit our HTML tutorial</a>
<br/>
<a href="http://www.w3schools.com/html/4" tabindex="4">Visit our HTML tutorial</a>
<br/>
<a href="http://www.w3schools.com/html/5" tabindex="5">Visit our HTML tutorial</a>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: I'm working on the links on the document instead of the controls within a form.

Comment: Watch closer at my code... I added a simpler view with only links. At the first solution not all tags within the forum. see Button

Comment: I'm not trying to re-arranging the tab orders. I wanna keep the original order while a click or hit on some link will jump to another specific tab.

Comment: you mean that you don't want to re arrange tabindex attribute ?